# How to use grid layout for array of items in one column when other columns have only one item?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I am learning to use grid in CSS, but I don't know how to make the following layout.
I have my data like this:

```js
const data = {
  name: "someName",
  array: [
    {name: "someItem", value: someInteger},
    ...
  ],
  total: someInteger
}
```

I want to display it like this:

```
   3fr        3fr                1fr           1fr
+------+-----------------+------------------+-------+
| name | array[0].name   | array[0].value   |       | auto
+------+-----------------+------------------+-------| 
|      | array[i].name   | array[i].value   |       | auto
+------+-----------------+------------------+-------|
|      | array[n-1].name | array[n-1].value | total | auto
+------+-----------------+------------------+-------+
```

I am using `React` for my project. All the above items are `div` elements.

Comment: I would not recommend CSS-Grid here...this seem to be a `table`, it would make more sense to use one.

Comment: The proposed **HTML** output would be useful here,

Comment: well, I don't know how to do it by using tables also

Comment: then this is not your question, I guess you need first to know how to extract the values and do something with it :) Unless you do and did not show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution shows an example how to do that using JS without ReactJS. It won't be a problem to figure out how to do the same with ReactJS (if you really need it).

https://codepen.io/chumakoff/pen/LYYVebb

css:

```
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 3fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

JS:

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

const nameDiv = document.createElement("div");
nameDiv.innerText = data.name;
wrapper.appendChild(nameDiv);  

data.array.forEach((item, index) => {
  const nameDiv = document.createElement("div");
  nameDiv.innerText = item.name;
  wrapper.appendChild(nameDiv);

  const valueDiv = document.createElement("div");
  valueDiv.innerText = item.value;
  wrapper.appendChild(valueDiv);

  if (index != data.array.length - 1) {
    wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  }
})

const totalDiv = document.createElement("div");
totalDiv.innerText = data.total;
wrapper.appendChild(totalDiv);
```